# How to find the remaining time between two dates in a time zone in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do countdown for certain events using flipclock in Ruby on Rails.

I tried to find the time difference of an EST event.

```
time_diff = <%= (Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") - Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")).to_i.abs %>;
```

I tried to check if it was correct by doing a one hour difference but I am always getting wrong number of hours left.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I dont quite understand. Are this times correct by themselves, without subtraction them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("EST").local(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0) - Time.now).to_i.abs
```

---

The code in your question is equivalent to

```
(Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0) - Time.now).to_i.abs
```

You probably expect the first part of the expression to mean "18:14 EST" but it means "18:14 UTC… but show what time that was in EST".

It might clarify things if you note that

```
Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).in_time_zone("EST") == Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0)
```

because

```
Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).in_time_zone("EST").to_i == Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).to_i
```

but

```
Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).in_time_zone("EST").to_s != Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 18, 14, 0).to_s
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. It works. That is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please tell why the second time Time.now doesn't need the time zone conversion?

Comment: Happy to help :) And sure. If you and I are on the phone and we check our clocks at the same time, you might say it's 5 a.m. EST and I might say it's 10 a.m. UTC. But these are the same moment in time. So if one hour later you want to check elapsed time, you could compare your original time of "5 a.m. EST" to "now (6 a.m. EST)" or to "now (11 a.m. UTC") – it doesn't matter. They're the same time. `Time.now` is internally a time-zone-independent number. If you want to e.g. show it as a string, it will differ between zones,  but for calculations of elapsed time it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that Time.now is internally a time-zone-independent number.